# How to check the length of each child in a list and conditionally apply a class to the children of another

Tags: javascript, children, css-selectors

I've been searching and searching for the solution to this, but I'm quite new to javascript and I must be missing something obvious.

What I'm trying to do is check each nth-child li by number to see whether they're empty or not, and, if they do contain something, add a class to the corresponding nth-child of another element.

This is what I've ended up at:

```
if ($('#availList ul li:nth-child(1)').text().length > 0){
$('map area:nth-child(1)').addClass("areaSold");
}
```

While firebug doesn't have any syntax errors, it doesn't seem to matter if the li is empty or not, because the class will always be applied.

I *must* be doing something thoroughly dense.

**UPDATE:**

[jsfiddle.net/filmcryptic/ed8LF/1](http://jsfiddle.net/filmcryptic/ed8LF/1)

This actually works as intended... Which means that something is messing up on the site:

Gah.

**UPDATE 2:**

It works! Thanks blender_noob!

Comment: pls create example http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Done! It looks like it actually works outside of the messy template I've been given. I'm just trying to figure out why it's not working on the site...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a jsFiddle below. Based on my understanding on your question, you want to add a class to the li if it contains a certain text on it. Please update me if this answers your question. Thanks

```
$(function(){
  $('#availList li').each(function(i,val){
     if($(this).text() == "Area Sold"){
       $('#mapArea li:nth-child('+(i+1)+')').addClass('areaSold');
     }else{
       $('#mapArea li:nth-child('+(i+1)+')').addClass('notSold');
     } 
  });
});
```

**Check sample here:**
http://jsfiddle.net/tBLhN/

Comment: Hi blender_noob, thanks! This is actually what I was trying to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/filmcryptic/ed8LF/1/ however, it seems like it works! which means that I must have messed up on my site implementation http://dinsdalecourt2.catalystcreative.net/plans/korimako

Comment: @MichaelTysoe your welcome! You can also check this updated answer if you are looking into other option: http://jsfiddle.net/tBLhN/2/